# How to add a buttom that is always visible after a scrollviewer?

Tags: wpf, xaml, scrollviewer

I have a ScrollViewer which includes a lot of content (datagrids, stackpanels, textboxes, labels, etc...), and outside of it I want to add a button (PRINT), and it is important that the button is not part of the ScrollViewer. My goal is that the top 90% of my screen is the scrollviewer and the bottom 10% is a "frozen panel" that always shows the PRINT button, and this should remain true when maximized and minimized.

After having a lo of problems with 'the property content is set more then once' I realized I need to add both my ScrollViewer and the Button inside another container, so far the only one that seems to work is GRID - but honestly after you read this if you have anything else to recommend I am open to suggestions, I only used GRID because it seemed to almost give me what I wanted.

This is my code right now:

```
[Code]
<Window DataContext="{Binding PrintView, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" Width="900">

    <Grid Height="Auto">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>        

        <ScrollViewer Name="PrintView" Grid.Row="0" Height="Auto">
            <StackPanel>
        ... a LOT of stuff ...
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>

        <Button Content="Print"
                Margin="0,20,0,20"
                Height="50"
                Width="150"
                FontSize="24"
                FontWeight="Bold"
                Grid.Row="1"
                />
    </Grid>
</Window>
[Code]
```

When done like this my ScrollViewer doesn't have a Scrollbar so I see the first page but I cannot scroll down, also there is no PRINT button seen
One interesting test was to change the following:

```
<ScrollViewer Name="Apercu" Grid.Row="0" Height="600">
```

Now I see my scrollbar again (and I can scroll) and my PRINT button is beneth it and always visible (this is almost perfect) but when I maximumize my window the ScrollViewer stays 600 of height and as such well it doesn't acctually maximize (everything below the PRINT button is just white).

Any ideas? Is there another way I could specify my HEIGHTS or is there a different control I should be using (not GRID)?
Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it ...

```
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

And remove height from ScollViewer